# Setting UISearchbar background color to white in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I am trying to change the background color of the UISearchbar. I am able to set the background to any color but white. Not sure why white does not get set. I am using the below code snippets to set the color. I have an extension method to get the textField. So, you can assume that textField exists.

```
searchBar.backgroundColor = .white
searchBar.textField?.backgroundColor = .white
```

It always has gray color when I set it to white.
[image]

However, if I use a color other than white it shows up that color.

```
searchBar.textField?.backgroundColor = .blue
```

[image]

Any idea what is wrong here.

Answer (score 9):

The only reliable way I have found to do this is to set the `searchTextField`'s `.borderStyle` to `.none` and manually set the layer's `cornerRadius` to match what the default border style would be. Something like:

```
self.searchBar.searchTextField.borderStyle = .none
self.searchBar.searchTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 10
self.searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .white
```

Comment: This trick has worked with me, but this is so weird, I don't know why the white color doesn't work while the other colors are working perfectly!

Comment: Thanks, it was driving me mad, super weird bur it works, iOS 15.4.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    searchController.searchBar.textField.backgroundColor = .white
}
```